# Install4j Zipped .sh for Linux

Tags: linux, install4j

I am generating a Unix/Linux GUI installer with install4j. The problem is that when users try to download the .sh, the browser opens the script's text instead of prompting to download. 
(I know this doesn't depend on install4j and is the browser's behavior).

I also know that the are Linux archive installers, but I need a GUI installer.

Is there a way to have a zipped .sh and have the best of both worlds?

If there is no solution and I must just zip the .sh manually before uploading, I should upload my installer two times, one zipped to manually download from my web, and another unzipped to be referenced by updates.xml, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 8.x there is no functionality to zip the .sh file by the install4j compiler, you would have to perform the zipping as part of your build process. I've created an issue for it.